# Is there an open source Bitcoin exchange?

Tags: exchanges

I just found [this project](https://github.com/enmaku/btc_exchange), which is described a.t.m as a learning project.

Is there a more serious, open source Bitcoin exchange? I'm aware exchanging BTC for fiat money can be quite complex, and might not fit an open source model, but an exchange specializing in crypto-currencies shouldn't be that complicated to setup, so I think there is room for an open source one.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Intersango is an open source exchange that is used at [intersango.com](http://www.intersango.com), which is an exchange operated by [The Bitcoin Consultancy](https://bitcoinconsultancy.com/). The open source project that can be found [here](http://gitorious.org/intersango) is released under the [GNU Affero General Public License](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/agpl.html).

For more info on how to set it up, see this post on the bitcointalk forums: [Intersango HOWTO - Build your own Bitcoin Exchange Web Site!](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=35812.0)

Comment: Nice, I missed / forgot about that. But how does it work? Specifically, how does one get fiat money in and out of the exchange? https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=35812.msg564823#msg564823

Comment: I'm not sure, haven't used it myself, but the second post in that thread says this: "the bank statement parser... Until now, you must access your Internet Banking and export your bank statement to a CSV or TXT file, to import it into Internsango using some scripts under the intersango/cron directory". I guess that every user is assigned a code to use when depositing to your bank account and that the parser mentioned reads your bank statement and credits the right accounts by reading the bank statement.

Comment: Ah, so the actual deposit is (as I thought) not automated yet. Thanks.

Comment: Some unfinished code here:
https://github.com/ghughes/xchgb

Comment: Also https://github.com/davout/bitcoin-central which apparently runs https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Bitcoin-Central

Answer (score 12):

The code that [Intersango](https://intersango.com/) runs is no longer open source as I understand it.

The Australian [World Bitcoin Exchange](https://www.worldbitcoinexchange.com/) uses a [heavily modified](https://github.com/dooglus/intersango/commits/aud) version of the old open source Intersango code, and remains open source.

Full disclosure: I'm the one who heavily modified it.  :)

Fiat deposits and withdrawals are handled manually.  For a while we looked into automating the process, but the bank charges more for the necessary [banking API](http://www.xero.com/) than the  exchange generates in commission.

Comment: How would you describe the state of this modified code? If it was to be used for an exchange, would it still need a lot of work? Is it well structured, buggy, etc.?

Comment: The code is live on WBX right now.  It handles modest amounts of volume - see http://bitcoincharts.com/markets/wbxAUD.html - at the time of writing it's moved 4500 BTC in the last 30 days.  It's stable, and pretty well structured.

Comment: I've made it configurable from a config file.  It only deals in a single currency pair (BTC <-> AUD).  It's easy to set it up to use something other than AUD, but getting it to trade multiple fiat currencies would be quite a rewrite.  That's what the closed source version of Intersango was - a rewrite for multiple currency pairs, and also separating the front and back ends.  This open source code has no such separation.

Comment: Excellent! I am glad to hear that it is in such good shape.

Comment: Would you be interested in creating an exchange between [Profit Points](http://www.open-org.com) and Bitcoins? Profit Points is a virtual currency. Contributors to Open-org.com earn Profit Points for their contributions. If you are interested, please write to me at mrdavidandersen ( a t ) gmail . com.

Answer (score 2):

The bitcoin-central.net exchange claims to be open as well, but they are currently(as of March 2nd 2013) "down for maintenance". The code can be found at [github](https://github.com/davout/bitcoin-central) and bitcoin-central is part of the [paymium](http://paymium.com/) payment network.

The network, including bitcoin-central, is somewhat backed by the french taxpayer:

> The ﬁrst ﬁnancially registered Bitcoin exchange,
>   bitcoin‑central.net is the leading European exchange running without
>   disruption since January 2011.
>
> Customer deposits in Euros are held separately by Aqoba, licensed as a
>   payment institution by Banque of France. A debit card will be offered
>   soon to veriﬁed account holders.

Answer (score 1):

Try this Chinese opensource project http://www.peat.io/

They've released their source code under the MIT License, and claim to have a fully functional platform.

Comment: https://github.com/peatio/peatio

Answer (score 0):

With a [recent news on bitcoin](http://techcrunch.com/2014/03/03/mt-gox-source-code-leaked-by-hackers-along-with-team-information-customer-data/?utm_campaign=fb&ncid=fb), it is claimed that the source code for MtGox exchange was leaked.

So you can find partially their source code (~2000 line of php) in this [paste](http://pastebin.com/W8B3CGiN).

Comment: That would not qualify as "open source".