# Buying Bitcoins using Guyana Dollars

Tags: bitcoin-core

Does anyone know what is required to establish an exchange that accepts Guyana $ as payment for Bitcoins?

Comment: You want to make your own BTC exchange?
It looks like $1USD = $205.20GYD.

Comment: related: [What would it take to create my own Bitcoin exchange?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/18540/5406)

Answer (score 1):

You need a bank account in Guyana for people to deposit money. Then you need a server to run the exchange. For the software you can check the answer to this question: [Is there an open source Bitcoin exchange?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/1447/is-there-an-open-source-bitcoin-exchange)

If you don't want to run you own server you can look at this: http://www.buttercoin.com/#/