# Trickle Exchange System?

Tags: exchanges

This idea came to me while I was trying to trade Frozencoins. For a miner like me that has to wait ages to get coins, its nearly impossible to trade small amounts of Frozencoins. People usually ask for huge amounts, from a hundred to 10,000. What if, people who made buy orders had the option of a "trickle" payment?

Basically, lets say that I only have 100 Frozencoin for X amount of Bitcoins but someone wants to buy 200. A trickle exchange would allow the person buying the Fronzencoins to receive multiple payments from different people with varying amounts until he reached the total he wanted. The people would get paid back ( in the cryptocurrency he/she was trading them for ) at the exact same rate ( Maybe 0.00002 BTC for every 1 FZ ). If he/she thought the wait time is too long, he/she can keep the coins and cut off the buy order. Is this possible? If so, what would it take to implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yea this is possible, there's nothing stopping you from making a new exchange that does things differently. Although to start making one you're going to need serious programming knowledge.

Consider the following questions

- [Is there an open source Bitcoin exchange?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/1447/is-there-an-open-source-bitcoin-exchange?rq=1)
- [What is needed to make a bitcoin exchange?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/17007/what-is-needed-to-make-a-bitcoin-exchange)